# How to combine a rows inside array in typescript,

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to combine rows inside array?
I have a array like this:

`Array[0:[{act: "1"}, {price: "100"}], 1:[{act: "2"}, {price: "200"}]]`

I am expecting output like this:

```js
[
  {act: "1",price:" 100"},
  {act: "2",price:"200"}
]
```

Comment: Your objects in the output is not consistent, is this intentional?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: Do you want to flatten your array..?

Comment: yes this is intentional, could you please suggest me an idea.

Comment: The original array is no valid TypeScript/JavaScript syntax, is this pseudo-code? If yes: why? I suggest that you rewrite it into valid TS/JS. Regarding the inconsistent format of the intended resulting array, as @Stutje wrote: what's the logic behind different structure for the first and the second element of this array?

Comment: can subarrays have more than two properties?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.flat()`.

```
const input = [[{ act: "1" }, { price: "100" }], [{ act: "2" }, { price: "200" }]]
const output = input.flat()
console.log(output)
// [{ act: "1" }, { price: 100 }, { act: "2" }, { price: "200" }]
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'flat' does not exist on type '({ act: string; price?: undefined; } | { price: string; act?: undefined; })[][]'.   Getting this Error @Nick McCurdy

Comment: You need to add `"es2019"` or `"es2019.array"` to your `compilerOptions.lib`. If you do this, it's also assumed that your JS environment supports it. If not, you will need to add support.